# Take contents from a div and add it to a table on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of divs, each with a button. If someone clicks the button, I then need to add the content of that div to a table row.

I've got a fiddle that accomplishes the creation of a new table row upon button click. But, I'm not sure how to pull the appropriate content and put it into that newly created table row.

http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/535/

Here's an example of the div I need to pull into the table. The names of each box checked in that div needs to be added to the row.

```
<div class="widget">
   <h2>Title 1</h2>
   <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Option 1a" value="optiona">Option 1a</input>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Option 1b" value="optionb">Option 1b</input> 
   </form>
   <button href="#" title="" class="add-content">Add Content 1</button>
</div>
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k5ute7c7/

Changing your jQuery to this should do what you describe:

```
$('.add-content').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newRow = '<tr><td>' + $(this).siblings('h2').text() +'</td><td>';
    $(this).siblings('form').children('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('checked')){
            newRow += $(this)[0].nextSibling.nodeValue + '<br>';
        }
    });
    newRow += "</td></tr>";
    jQuery('table').append(newRow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get you started on how to get a `value`.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/yUfhL/536/)**

`var value = $('input[name=Option 1]:checked', '#myForm').val();`